# Train a polynomial regression model on multiple training sets in R?

Tags: r, regression

For my course in machine learning, I got an assignment to generate a number of training sets and train a polynomial model for each of these training sets with R. The hint was to use `lm()`.

My first idea was to do something like:

```
set.seed(128)
f <- function(x) 5*x^3 + 3*x^2 - 2*x^1 + 1 + 1
nrOfSets <- 100
nrOfSamples <- 10
predictions <- rep(0,nrOfSets)

for (i in 1:nrOfSets) {
    x <- runif(nrOfSamples, 0, 2)
    # function with noise
    y <- f(x) + rnorm(nrOfSamples, 0, 0.1)

    model <- lm(y ~ x)
    predictions[i] <- predict(model, data.frame(x=0.1))
}
```

which gives me `nrOfSets` predictions from which I can compute bias and variance. I was just wondering whether this is the correct way to do this or if there are more efficient ways to achieve something like this (for instance with vectorized operations instead of a `for`-loop).

Any suggestions are welcome (also about whether this is the right place to ask this question for instance).

Comment: Well, if you are into the code performance / best practices, I suggest you to post it on code review instead : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is there an easy way to merge this question to other platforms of stack exchange?

Comment: `nrOfSets` is undefined in your code snippet, and `predictions` is uninitialized.  It's best to include these (and a call to `set.seed`) so that your example is self contained.

Comment: @MatthewDrury does this suffice?

Comment: You want to supply a fixed integer to `set.seed`, something like `set.seed(154)`.  This will allow other people to reproduce your exact results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but it's worth pointing out that

```
model <- lm(y ~ x)
```

trains a pure *linear* model on each of your data sets.  This *is*, in a reductive sense, a polynomial model, of degree 1.

In the spirit of the task though, you may want to generalize to higher degrees, which would be something like this

```
model <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))
```

The `I` takes a bit of experience to get used to, it says "interpret what is inside `I` as a function to apply to the columns or vectors that I reference".

The [book by Gelman and Hill](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) is an excellent reference for this kind of thing.  It includes lots of clean example code, and will, for example, help you plot the results of these kinds of experiments.

Comment: Thanks for the hints and the reference. I know, but I would like to take into account multiple degrees of polynomials and I am still looking how I could do that...

Comment: That's what my small example does, it will fit a cubic regression curve.

Comment: I rather meant for different allowed degrees of polynomials. Something like once for `lm(y~x)` and then `lm(y~x + I(x^2))`, etc... (or is this a bad idea?)

Comment: Whether it's a bad idea depends on what you're doing.  It seems like you are exploring the methods and the consequences of different decisions.  In that case, it's a very good idea to experiment and gain intuition.